# 'None' is printed when I want 'True' for input 5

Tags: python

In this primality test program, 'None' is printed when I input a prime, instead of 'True'. How can I get it to print 'True'?.

```
    def main():
        import math
        def check_n(n):
            n_s = int(math.sqrt(n))
            for i in range(2, n_s):
                if (n_s % i) == 0:
                    return False
                    break
                else:
                    return True
        def msg():
            n = int(input('Enter a number, I will return True if it is a prime'))
            return n

        print(check_n(msg()))

    main()
```

Comment: Is there any special reason to have 2 functions inside another function ?

Comment: And you probably shouldn't put the import statement in a function

Comment: You really shouldn't `def main()` in a python script.

Comment: range(2,2) isn't iterable https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your range is (2,2) or `None` when you choose anything less than 9.
So to solve your first problem: add 2 to `n_s` (for input 3)

You also have a problem with your logic.

Your `for` loop should be checking that `n` mod `i` is 0, not `n_s`.

This should work:

```
def main():
    import math
    def check_n(n):
        n_s = int(math.sqrt(n)+1)
        for i in range(2, n_s):
            if (n % i) == 0:
                return False
        return True
    def msg():
        n = int(input('Enter a number, I will return True if it is a prime'))
        return n

    print(check_n(msg()))

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `int(math.sqrt(n))` to `int(math.sqrt(n)+1)`, because `range` runs until `n_s-1`. So if the input is 5, `range(2,int(math.sqrt(5)))` is just `range(2,2)`, which is empty.

In addition, you need to take the `return True` outside of the `for` loop, otherwise your code may stop in a too early stage. You also don't need the `break` statement after `return False` (the function will never arrive to that line, as it will return `False` if it enters to that `if` statement).

Finally, change `if (n_s % i) == 0:` to `if (n % i) == 0:`, as you need to check if `n` is divisible by `i` (and not its square root).

Here is a more clean version:

```
import math
def check_n(n):
    n_s = int(math.sqrt(n)+1)
    for i in range(2, n_s):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True
def msg():
    n = int(input('Enter a number, I will return True if it is a prime'))
    return n
print(check_n(msg()))
```

Answer (score 1):

First: Your break statement is redundant.

Second: For values such as 3 the for loop is never executing because value 
        n_s is less than 2 and since the for loop isn't executing the 
        python is returning the default value None(which is returned when 
        no value is specified).
Hence your check_n(n) function has to be

```
def check_n(n):
    n_s = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for i in range(2, n_s + 1):
        if (n_s % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

one liner :

```
check_n = lambda n : sum([i for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)+1)) if n % i == 0]) == 0
```

don't overcomplicate things ..